# Entity Connection in a Modular Prism Application

Tags: entity-framework, prism, connection-string

**Connection String Meta :**

```
                res://Xz.Business.xModule/Model.RecordzModel.csdl|
                res://Xz.Business.xModule/Model.RecordzModel.ssdl|
                res://Xz.Business.xModule/Model.RecordzModel.msl;
```

---

**Errors :**

*After Adding Business.xModule into the Config File's URI s :*

```
+       base    {"Unable to load the specified metadata resource."} System.Data.EntityException {System.Data.MetadataException}
```

--
*After Adding Xz.Business.xModule into the Config File's URI s  :*

```
+       base    {"Unable to resolve assembly 'Xz.Business.xModule'.":null}  System.IO.IOException {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}
```

---

**xModule Info :**

The Assembly Name : Business.xModule

Default Namespace : Xz.Business.xModule

---

**Folder Locations :**

Solution Folder and xModule Module Folder

Solution Location..\x1\x2\xModule Location

Modules Location
Solution Location..\Build

".." Means a folder back.

---

**Notes :**

1. The modules have Post-Build Action which place the result assemblies into the "Build Folder"
2. Other pieces of the config are correct.
3. Unity, SQL CE, EF 5.0 were used.

How to resolve this Entity Connection Problem ?

Comment: The first exception looks like the artifacts are either not embedded in your dll or the path is not correct. The second exception can be thrown by anything. Show the full stack trace - it should at least tell where it is being thrown from.

Comment: I have provided the folder structure how should I set the correct path for this, seemed the artifacts were embeded.

Comment: With the Folder structure I provided tell me Is this correct or how should I change it : "res://../x1/x2/Business.xModule/Model.RecordzModel.csdl"

Comment: Use ILDASM or reflector to see the artifact real name. You may also try using `res://*/` instead of `res://` to ignore folders.

Comment: I changed them to "res://*/Business.xModule.RecordzModel.csdl" (Made them all in this style. DotPeek & ILSpy show this as the name : Business.xModule, and the location is what we were aware of (a static file-based location)

Comment: The Error is still : "Unable to load the specified metadata resource."

Comment: Try loading the resources manually using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)` once you are able to do that you will now the name to put in the config. Note that in this case you need to provide a full name without the `res://` or `res://*/`

Comment: I'll try that and some other things came into my mind to find best option here. After it be finished I'll change the Entity Connection into a code-based version. Though here we are talking about this config cause I'm eager to know what was the problem and maybe fix this a bit complex architecture. (Dirs and Namings).

Comment: I tried based on what you've said and edited my post, please take a look.

Comment: I don't think you need this part assembly.GetName().Name - you are using assembly instance so it would be redundant (unless your resource is really called like this) - use the resource name exactly as it appears in ILDASM.

Comment: Hi again, You helped me solve this issue, provide a 2 line answer which I could mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have problems loading embedded resources I usually use ILDASM or reflector to get the resource name. In EF connection string you can provide a path to artifacts saved as files or embedded resources. `res://` indicates embedded resource. After `res://` you put exact resource name (as showed by ILDASM). If the resource is in a folder you can use `res://*/{resourceName}` to say you want to search in all folders.

Comment: The delay was because I didn't get notification on this post.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want to use another database, orm or service, you will regret doing it like this. You could use the [repository pattern](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/). This abstracts all this away. You can implement all repositories in one module that handles the data, and the others can use them with dependency injection. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp) explains more.

Comment: I'm trying to to that, and now the problem was the connection string, The repository is defined, some simple modules were built and now trying to bring the data for them. Will study more what you have provided. What I did wrong which you are talking about ?

Comment: Also +1 for the info and thanks, I've provided more comments to my post, If you found what was wrong here please share with me.

Comment: Also there is no problem for DI, If the connection be correct I think that phase also could be done. Yet I just referenced the DAL, If you think it could be a part of the problem I could inject it with the appropriate attribute as needed. Am I right ?

Comment: Well it depends on your system. In my situation I didn't want to be dependent on any classes of the DAL, especially not generated model classes in my case. So I only interact with interfaces that represent my data (e.g. ICustomer). So my modules have only one dependency, and that is a class library with all the interfaces. No other references are made. As soon as you reference your modules with each other, they aren't really independent modules anymore. I hope this answers your question and I understood it correctly...

Comment: Yes, I understand I'm turning my code into a more pattern-based and more interface-based structure, I made an IRepo.. and Repo..Base but and another specific Repo... Which Implemented/Inherited them. All of them are in a DAL Assembly which here I named it xModule and that's not really a module. Each module needed it I reference it there. Anyway I still looking to any problems you've found in my strategy. What You are saying could be more clear with a simple example addressing the issues. (Not needed the real code)